Failure for clever referencing of "create-theorem" due to recent update
In create-theorem, there is a macro \NameTheorem for (re)claiming the title and referencing names etc. for theorem-like environments, which can be then used by \CreateTheorem. Consider the following example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{create-theorem}

\NameTheorem{theorem}{heading={THM},crefname={{THM}{THMs}}}
\CreateTheorem{theorem}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    Text.
\end{theorem}

\cref{thm}

\end{document}

With a latest TeX distribution, say, an up-to-dated TeX Live 2024, the result would be:

As you may have noticed, the key crefname does not seem to be effective: instead of theorem 1, one should get THM 1 via the \cref.
However, as I remember, the same code would be able to give the correct result as of August 2024, and I didn't make any significant change to this package since then. May I ask what might have been changed in the TeX world (say, update in expl3) that could lead to such failure? Thanks so much!

To be frank, it's somewhat shameful for me to ask this question, since I am the developer of the package create-theorem. However, having struggled a whole morning without getting any clue, I finally decided to ask this question and see if I might get any luck here.


I can only check later but assuming that this is based on cleveref, search for my recent answers ...

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for the suggestion! After some searching and reading I found that your patch in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730164 works. However, since this does not seem to be the recommended solution as you stated, I am kind of hesitating whether I should incorporate this package to my package crefthe or not.

As you have your own command you should be able to set the alias explicitly with crefalias.
